# Probability of picking rooms

Tags: probability

Suppose there are 15 rooms among which a person in present in one room.
If i pick 5 rooms out of them, what is the probability that the person is present in one of the 5 rooms selected?

No of ways we can pick 5 rooms: 15C5,
So answer could be x/15C5

Where am i stuck is how to figure out x? Among 15C5 selections, which of them will contain that specific room in which the person is there?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be $\frac{1}{3}$, since we are splitting up the 15 total rooms into three sets of 5 rooms, and then seeing if the person is in one of the three sets? I feel like I'm missing something though...

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Nope. The five rooms aren't fixed. It's not like there are three groups of five to chose from. We have tho chose all the five members of the group.

Comment: @Gummybears oh ya, combinations... duh. I really dropped the ball on that one. Time to take another probability course... been way too focused on real analysis....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

There is only one way to choose the occupied room, what about the rest ?

*Answer:*

Why confused ? $ Pr = {1\choose 1}{14\choose4} / {15\choose 5}$

Of course, you can leave out the ${1\choose 1}$ , but it shows exactly what you did .

Comment: I have given a "regular" formula, which may be of use in more complex problems, but here, really, you can simply compute it as $5/15 = 1/3$

Answer (score 1):

First, chose the single door that has the person behind it. Then, the four remaining doors can be chosen in any fashion.

Basically, how will you chose 4 doors from a total of 14 doors (as we have already chosen the one with the person behind it)?